# WPF DataGrid Element Name of other DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have two Datagrid Template column. 
1) Fist column is a Combobox 
2) Second column with Extended IntergerUpDown control

I need to set the IntegerUpDown Maximum value based on the Combox box SelectedItem value.

Please help me how to accomplish this. Sample xaml below.

```
<Grid><DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding List1}" Name="x1">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ColorTemplate">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.List2, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" 
                                      DisplayMemberPath="Name"  SelectedValue="{Binding ColourId}" SelectedValuePath="Id" Tag="{Binding Id}"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="discussTemplate" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                         />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="UPDown" Width="Auto">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <extToolkit:IntegerUpDown AllowSpin="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Minimum="0"
                                                  x:Name="updown"
                                                  Maximum="{Binding ???}" >

                            </extToolkit:IntegerUpDown>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply bind to the value of your itemsrow? so if ColourID is the property of your itemsrow which is set by your combobox. you can bind your Maximum to ColourID

```
<extToolkit:IntegerUpDown AllowSpin="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Minimum="0"
                          Maximum="{Binding ColourId}" >
</extToolkit:IntegerUpDown>
```

Comment: +1, Also dont forget to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your item class (which has `ColourId` property declared in it).

Comment: There is a value in Attribute "TAG" in CombBox that value has to be set as a Maximum of IntergerUpDown Control.